# How to remove Unity Icon gloss

Tags: unity, themes, icons

I recently installed the Nitrux–UMD icon theme, and I'm wondering how to turn off the Unity gloss that's being applied over the unity bar icons.

This is how it looks—

[image]

This is how it should look—

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can try to edit the images in the /usr/share/unity/***folder with your version number***..
In my case in Ubuntu 12.04 the versrion is **"5"**, if you have Ubuntu 12.10 the version is **"6"**.

1. Go to the Terminal and type `cd /usr/share/unity/5/` or `cd /usr/share/unity/6/`
2. There are 3 icons named **launcher_icon_shine_54.png, launcher_icon_shine_170.png and launcher_icon_shine_150.png** (I only edited the launcher_icon_shine_54.png image, feel free to edit the 3 files)
3. Make a backup of this file (or the 3 files) with `sudo cp -p launcher_icon_shine_54.png launcher_icon_shine_54.png.bak`
4. Open an application to edit the image, (in my case gimp) to install
   [image: Install via the software center]
5. In the Terminal type `sudo gimp /usr/share/unity/5/launcher_icon_shine_54.png` or `sudo gimp /usr/share/unity/6/launcher_icon_shine_54.png`
6. You can edit the image according to your needs (I pick the "eraser tool" and delated the all shine mask)
7. Save your image, logout and login.

Here you have my result:

Before edit the image:
[image]

After edit the iamge:
[image]

Remember that you have a backup , So if anything goes wrong rename the backup **"launcher_icon_shine_54.png.bak"** to **"launcher_icon_shine_54.png"** logout and login to have the original unity.

I hope this would be useful.